# Material Doesn't catch light shining on it from using a Geometry and Mix Shader node

Tags: materials

I created the following node setup to place an image on 1 side of a plane and have the other side white.

[image: Mix Shader setup]

[image: Render Preview]

The issue is now the material will not catch any light from a lightsource.

The following node setup works but then the image is on both sides of the plane.

[image: Principle Shader]

[image: Render Preview with Lights]

**Question**

How can I use Geometry and a mix shader in my material and have it catch light?

Comment: @RobertGützkow I guess I would only want 1 side to be diffused and the side with the image to have specular reflections.

Comment: Then you can simply use your first node setup and add a *Principled BSDF* between the *Image Texture* node and the *Mix Shader*. Set the *Specular* value of the *Principled BSDF* to control the amount of specular reflection. Does that solve your problem?

Comment: @RobertGützkow I have added some render preview images. The 4th image with the stem lights, see how they cast a light onto the image?

Comment: The first setup is almost right, you just shouldn't connect the *Image Texture* directly to the *Mix Shader*. The green sockets  should be used to connect *Shaders*. Take the nodes from the second setup (without the Material Output) and connect the output of the *Principled BSDF* with the *Mix Shader*.

Comment: @RobertGützkow Awesome! Do you want to write that for an answer so I can mark answered?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first node setup is almost right, except that you're missing a shader between the *Image Texture* node and the *Mix Shader*. The green sockets indicate that the input to the *Mix Shader* should usually be the output of another shader, for instance the *Principled BSDF*.

Start from the node setup from your first screenshot and add a *Principled BSDF*. Disconnect the *Image Texture* node from the *Mix Shader*.

Connect the:

- *Color* output socket of *Image Texture* node to the *Base Color* input socket of the *Principled BSDF* node
- *BSDF* output socket of the *Principled BSDF* to the upper *Shader* input socket of the *Mix Shader*

Adjust the properties of the *Principled BSDF* to get the desired look. *Specular* controls the amount of specular reflections.

[image: Node setup]

[image: Front]

[image: Back]